# texttabs not being set using rest api create envelope

Tags: docusignapi

Wondering what I am missing or doing wrong here as the value for the tabs are not being set when creating the envelope.

In the JSON code below I am trying to default values for the text tabs for recipient 5.

```
{
            "emailSubject":"Allowance Agreement - AK Anne Klein Footwear  -  ytd .doc",
            "emailBlurb":"DEV - Please complete the Vendor Allowance Agreement required for your Supplier setup with Zappos.com or 6pm.com. \n\n Please reach out to your Vendor Support team member or vendorsupport@zappos.com with any questions.",
            "status":"sent",
            "compositeTemplates":[
            {
                "compositeTemplateId": "1",                    
                "inlineTemplates":[
                    {
                        "sequence":"1",
                         "documents": [
                            {
                            "documentId": "1",
                            "name": "Allowance Agreement - AK Anne Klein Footwear  -  ytd .doc.doc"
                            }
                            ],
                        "customFields": {
                                "textCustomFields": [
                                    {
                                        "name": "Node ID",
                                        "required": "true",
                                        "show": "true",
                                        "value": "658824"
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                        "recipients":{
                        "signers":[
                            {
                                "email":"email@email.com",
                                "name":"v",
                                "recipientId":1,
                                "roleName":"Vendor"
                            },
                            {
                                "email":"email@email.com",
                                "name":"test",
                                "recipientId":2,
                                "roleName":"Vendor Support"
                            },
                            {
                                "email":"email@email.com",
                                "name":"ap",
                                "recipientId":3,
                                "roleName":"AP"
                            },
                            { 
                                "email":"email@email.com",
                                "name":"f",
                                "recipientId":4,
                                "roleName":"Finance"
                            },
                            {
                                "email":"email@email.com",
                                "name":"ap",
                                "recipientId":5,
                                "roleName":"AP2",
                                "tabs":{
                               "textTabs":[
                                  {
                                     "tabLabel":"txtVendorId",
                                     "value":"100023"
                                  },
                                  {
                                     "tabLabel":"txtSupplierName",
                                     "value":"AK Anne Klein Footwear"
                                  },
                                  {
                                     "tabLabel":"txtSupplierId",
                                     "value":"253"
                                  }
                               ]
                        }}
                        ]
                    }                    
                    }
                    ],
                "serverTemplates":[
                    {
                        "sequence":"2",
                        "templateId":"A3B4F6BB-639A-486F-8C84-826295142F21"
                    }
                    ]
                }
            ]
            }
```

When I look at the envelope tabs here is what I get for the 5th recipient:

```
"textTabs": [
      {
        "height": 22,
        "isPaymentAmount": "false",
        "validationPattern": "",
        "shared": "false",
        "requireInitialOnSharedChange": "false",
        "requireAll": "false",
        "name": "Text",
        "value": "",
        "width": 300,
        "required": "true",
        "locked": "false",
        "concealValueOnDocument": "false",
        "disableAutoSize": "false",
        "tabLabel": "txtVendorId",
        "font": "lucidaconsole",
        "fontColor": "black",
        "fontSize": "size9",
        "documentId": "1",
        "recipientId": "5",
        "pageNumber": "2",
        "xPosition": "217",
        "yPosition": "651",
        "tabId": "2179efb5-9f59-4bb7-895e-da868fba9919"
      },
      {
        "height": 22,
        "isPaymentAmount": "false",
        "validationPattern": "",
        "shared": "false",
        "requireInitialOnSharedChange": "false",
        "requireAll": "false",
        "name": "Text",
        "value": "",
        "width": 342,
        "required": "true",
        "locked": "false",
        "concealValueOnDocument": "false",
        "disableAutoSize": "false",
        "tabLabel": "txtSupplierName",
        "font": "lucidaconsole",
        "fontColor": "black",
        "fontSize": "size9",
        "documentId": "1",
        "recipientId": "5",
        "pageNumber": "2",
        "xPosition": "172",
        "yPosition": "670",
        "tabId": "2c6e59b1-6a4f-4f5f-a873-33398c78e408"
      },
      {
        "height": 22,
        "isPaymentAmount": "false",
        "validationPattern": "",
        "shared": "false",
        "requireInitialOnSharedChange": "false",
        "requireAll": "false",
        "name": "Text",
        "value": "",
        "width": 354,
        "required": "true",
        "locked": "false",
        "concealValueOnDocument": "false",
        "disableAutoSize": "false",
        "tabLabel": "txtSupplierId",
        "font": "lucidaconsole",
        "fontColor": "black",
        "fontSize": "size9",
        "documentId": "1",
        "recipientId": "5",
        "pageNumber": "2",
        "xPosition": "172",
        "yPosition": "690",
        "tabId": "614eb20b-5536-45db-b64a-84a475cdc44d"
      }
    ]
```

*** EDIT ***
adding final part of envelopes tabs and screen captures of recipients and one tab...

```
},
  "isBulkRecipient": "false",
  "name": "ap",
  "email": "email@email.com",
  "recipientId": "5",
  "recipientIdGuid": "77e255d8-a6d6-47a8-98ee-0f3829631d76",
  "requireIdLookup": "false",
  "userId": "8d7f443b-7adf-4cfa-8368-296aee88e959",
  "routingOrder": "5",
  "roleName": "AP2",
  "status": "created",
  "totalTabCount": "5"
}
```

[image: Recipients]

[image: Field sample]

*** Workaround ***

Since I was not able to set the tab values at creation time I tried the following:

1. Tried to create a PUT request to update the tabs using the uri for the tab for the recipient /envelopeid/recipients/5/tabs and passing the JSON for the text tabs as.

   {
       "textTabs":[
           {
               "tabLabel": "txtVendorId",
               "value":"123"
           }
       ]
   }

Passing the JSON above I would get a response that the tab was not found on the envelope

```
{
  "requireAll": "false",
  "concealValueOnDocument": "false",
  "disableAutoSize": "false",
  "recipientId": "5",
  "tabId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
  "errorDetails": {
    "errorCode": "INVALID_TAB_OPERATION",
    "message": "The Tab specified is not valid for the requested operation.  The Tab specified is not valid for the requested operation. Tab not found in envelope."
}
```

2. My second step was to actually get the tabId value from the created envelope instead of using the tab lable (something that I would not have before creating the envelope).

By calling /envelopeid/recipients/5/tabs with the tabId in the JSON instead like

```
{
    "textTabs":[
        {
            "tabId": "57135910-fe34-417d-a4e3-fc7d6c4a42ed",
            "value":"123"
        }
    ]
}
```

Then the field value got updated correctly.

In conclusion, for my workaround will need three calls to DocuSign to be able to set the default values for this recipient:

- Create Envelope
- Get Recipient tabs (to get value of tab ids)
- Update tab values using tab ids.

Comment: Where do the tabs exist that you're assigning the values from? In server template 'A3B4F6BB-639A-486F-8C84-826295142F21'?

Comment: Yes, they are in the template. What I am trying to do is assign the template to the document and then defauting a few of the values for one of the users.

Comment: @AndrewWilson Andrew, do I need to assign in a different location due to the tabs being in the template?

Comment: @AndrewWilson just wanted to follow up and see if due to the tabs being in the template if they are supposed to be assigned in a different way

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Are you positive you are correctly matching your recipients to valid roles you've configured on the Template?

For instance, I see that for recipient #5 you are assigning them to the `"AP2"` role, does that exact role exist in your template when you login to the website and view the template?

Comment: the role on recipient #5 is set to AP2, I set the name to ap as a placeholder. "name":"ap",
                                "recipientId":5,
                                "roleName":"AP2",

Comment: I have added the screen capture of the recipients as well as one of the fields

Comment: As you can see in my code I am assigning the tabs to `"AP2"` with the name of `"ap"` so I don't see where I am missing something.

Comment: Any other things that you might think of Ergin?

Comment: Nothing obvious I can think of, at this point I would start isolating the bits and pieces of your code that work.  What happens if you try to assign the `textTabs` to the first recipient?  What about assigning them a different `roleName` on the template?  I would also test sending an envelope with just one recipient and tabs assigned to them and see what happens.  Lastly, I was always a little confused with the `sequence` param under the server template property, and the `defaultRecipient` property.  You might want to test around those as well.

Comment: Thank you Ergin, I have updated my post with a workaround that I will be implementing to be able to accomplish what I need.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry for the very long delay on an answer, your JSON needs one small tweek.

You need to change your `sequence` of your `serverTemplates` to `1`, assigning the values to the same template.

```
"serverTemplates":[
  {
    "sequence":"1",
  }
```

This will remove the need for the GET/PUT (although you can still do the GET to verify information if you'd like)

[image: Picture of Successful Test]